# Looking for a meta-RPG about escapism in RPGs and the reality of one's actions

Tags: product-identification

I could swear that I saw a link to this somewhere on TVTropes.org, but I can't seem to find it. There was a website detailing a sort of a bolt-on RPG added to a regular game session. All of the players make "character sheets" with their name under "Patient Name" and then a section for their character name, then something indicating patient psychoses. After each gaming session, the GM sits everyone down and informs them that their prior session was a delusional episode which they need to discuss for the purposes of therapy. There was a standard set of questions meant to draw out from the players how their in-character actions — small-scale genocide of kobold populations, looting of tombs, wholesale destruction of habitat, etc — were extremely anti-social behaviors when compared to how we operate IRL.

It was incredibly heavy-handed, Anvilicious to use TV Tropes terminology, but I thought it was an interesting concept and I wanted to pass it on to someone I know.

Comment: Not exactly the answer, but well worth mentioning is the Fiasco playset [Dysfunctions and Dragons](http://www.bullypulpitgames.com/wiki/index.php?title=Dysfunctions_And_Dragons).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That RPG is [John Tynes's **Power Kill**](http://johntynes.com/revland2000/rl_powerkill.html), the B-side to **Puppetland.**

Comment: I find the premise of Power Kill to be somewhat lacking; it seems to imply that the concepts involved are limited to RPGs specifically, but even outside of them there are plenty of stories featuring protagonists who do things that would be considered against the law out-of-universe and in many cases even in-universe.